# Trying to load a dynamic path for image using React useEffect and useState from node.js server

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to load an image from a fetch done from a server.  Images are saved in an assets folder on the front end.  I end up getting: " Error: Cannot load module './' "  I assume it is because the state is not populated when trying to return the HTML.  When I load just the path name, it works, but not when trying to load the img?  Any help to a self taught coder would be helpful.

```
    export default function PlaceBids(props) {

    const [quoteImage, setQuoteImage] = useState('')
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/bids?bids=' + props.quoteNumber, {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.loggedIn === false) {
                    return null
                }
                if (res.success) {
                    setQuoteImage(res.quoteImage)
                }
                else {
                    setQuoteImage(res.quoteImage)
                }
            }
            )
    }, [])

return (
   <div>
     <img src={require('../assets/models/' + quoteImage)}/>
   </div>
)
}
```

Comment: I see two problems here. 1) you are using react incorrectly. load the image also using react js. right now, you are trying to load it directly in HTML DOM, not react DOM. 2) because of problem 1, when you finish calling the api, and puts the image in your folders, nobody is loading the image. get a react component to show the image. problem solved.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for your response!  In this case, the image is already saved in my folders on the front end, it is just the path that is loading dynamically.  It seems like the render is occurring before the useEffect is called and the path is non existent.

Comment: right, right, i stand corrected. i read your question incorrectly. you are using react correctly. my apologies for the same. i am still new to react, but, my understanding is, there are two renders that are happening here, as is the normal with react. first render happens, right away, and then, useeffect happens, calling the api, and triggers a state change, causing the second render.

Comment: if you have the full path name of the image, why bother saving it to the local folder? why not use it directly? let me put a code in the answer block for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try.

```
//pass your api response to this

function ShowImage({ data }) {
    return (
        <div className="ShowImage">
          <img src={data.quoteImage} alt={"showing image here from api "}  />
        </div>
      );
}
```

This is how I would handle a simple image display in react JS. If you had (or could) put your code in a codesandbox or something, perhaps, I could test if this really works for you.

essentially, since, I am getting the full image URL from API, I bypass the local folder.

Render # 1

image will render, but there is no image, so it will simply say "showing image here form api".

then, useEffect will call the API, and when API succeeds, it trigers a state change and calls for render again, but this time, you are sending your API response.

Render # 2

Image renders using the image path at data.quoteImage.

*note : I am assuming it is a simple case of image display, for I am also a beginner. However, if this is something far more complicated, then, others in the community should be able to help you out.*